# how can we use ''$data'' with ''required'' in ajv?

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

I have a json schema like this :

```
let schema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties : {
    first: {
      type : 'object',
      properties : {
        foo : {type : 'string'}
      }
    },
    second: {
      type : 'object',
      properties : {
        bar : {type : 'boolean'}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to implement this condition:  if **{bar: true}** then "foo" is necessary (required)

something like this :

```
let schema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties : {
    first: {
      type : 'object',
      properties : {
        foo : {type : 'string'}
      }
    },
    second: {
      type : 'object',
      properties : {
        bar : {type : 'boolean'}
      },
      if:{
        bar : {const : 'true'}
      },
      then:{
        required : {'$data': '1/first/foo'}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it does not work!!!!

Comment: `'boolean'` inside quotes is a string, not a boolean, so the const comparison is not matching. Also, the value of the `required` property is an array, not an object.

Comment: all the phrase is inside quotes just for emphasis.that means `{bar : true}`.also, when use `$data` property the `required` can be object.the question is, how???